# linking results from 2 different php files pulled in via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I have 2 php files which pull in different query results (added below)

is there a way that i can link these results e.g.
I have added 2 pictures at the bottom the table on the right is after the 1st query (beacon.php)and the table on the left is after the call of Del.php

I have also attached example data image I have added a blue box around data i would like linked if possible so because the beacon 24,89,95 are present in both Q1(beacon.php) and Q2(Del.php) change the border of these cells and leave the rest of the cell border black is there a way to do this?

Q1 = Beacon.php

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT
beacon,location,date,
COUNT(location) AS counter 
FROM `test`.`test`
WHERE `date` = CURDATE() and `time` > NOW() - interval 40 second
GROUP BY beacon) AS SubQueryTable
ORDER BY SubQueryTable.counter DESC;';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$result = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Q2 = Del.php

```
$sql = "
SELECT beacon,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(max(`time`),min(`time`)), '%i.%s') 
AS `delivery_avg` 
FROM `test`.`test` 
where date = CURDATE()
and time > now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
group by beacon ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$result = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

html/javascript side

```
<style>
table {
padding: 10px 10px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;    
 text-align: center; 
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 40px;
 background-color: #8F8F8F;
}
</style>

<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
    $(`<td class='${i * 10 + j}'>${i * 10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
}
}

$.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
console.log(response);
var row;
$.each(response, function(index, item) {
    console.log(item);
    $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
});
});


function updateTable() {
//console.log('function called');
$('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
$.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
    $.each(response.query1, function(index, item) {
        console.log(item.beacon,item.location);
        //$('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
$(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
    });
});
}
var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 5000);
});

$.get('php/del.php', function(response) {
console.log(response);
var row;
$.each(response, function(index, item) {
    console.log(item);
if (item.delivery_avg <= 7.00) {
return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
} else if (item.delivery_avg >= 7.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 14.00) {
 return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'orange', 'border-width':'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
} else if (item.delivery_avg >= 14.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 20.00) {
return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'pink', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
} else if (item.delivery_avg >= 20.01) {
return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color': 'red', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
}
});
});
</script>
```

[image: t1+t2][image: data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it'd be best for MySQL to link the data.

```
SELECT
    beacon.beacon,
    beacon.location,
    beacon.date,
    beacon.counter,
    del.delivery_avg
FROM
(
    SELECT
        beacon,
        location,
        date,
        COUNT(location) AS counter
    FROM `test`.`test`
    WHERE `date = CURDATE()
    AND `time` > ( NOW() - INTERVAL 40 SECOND )
    GROUP BY beacon
) beacon
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        beacon,
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(MAX(`time`), MIN(`time`)), '%i.%s') AS delivery_avg
    FROM `test`.`test`
    WHERE date = CURDATE()
    AND time > ( NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE )
    GROUP BY beacon
) del ON beacon.beacon = del.beacon
ORDER BY beacon.counter DESC
```

Comment: If i run those separately I get results if i run it how you have written it it return no results

Comment: no results so if i run Q1 and Q2 separately it return results for the queries if i run the above that you wrote it returns no results

Comment: would it be easier if i attach a list of results to test against?